# MultiSelectList Exception when disabling the RootFrame

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, multi-select

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that uses a MultiSelectList. The general workflow should be that the user selects one or more items on the list, then clicks on a App bar button that opens up a Popup dialog. Since the dialog is smaller than the screen, the list should be disabled when the dialog is open.

There seems to be a problem in the disabling part of the frame.

The RootFrame of the application is a TransitionFrame.

Just before the popup is opened, the code calls

```
_frame.IsEnabled = false; (where _frame = RootFrame)
```

It seems that this call somehow generates an exception of the form:

```
Application_UnhandledException() System.Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.VisualStateManager_GoToState(Control reference, String StateName, Boolean useTransitions, Boolean& refreshInheritanceContext)
at System.Windows.VisualStateManager.GoToState(Control control, String stateName, Boolean useTransitions)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.ChangeVisualState(Boolean useTransitions)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnIsEnabledChanged(IsEnabledChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnIsEnabledChanged(Control control, EventArgs args)
at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

When I take out the _frame.IsEnabled = false call then there is no exception (and also nothing is disabled)

My suspicion is that the ToggleButton in the exception refers to the checkboxes of the MutliSelectList.

I am completely stuck and do not know how to debug anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you disable the **RootFrame**, you can directly disable the **MultiselectList**. When you disable **RootFrame**, all of the controls on the page are unvailable in addition to the ApplicationBar. So the dialog popup on the list is disable too.So I think it is not a good way. Wish this can help you